# how to include font awesome icons and how to bind in html

Tags: html, css, angularjs

this is my html code

```
<body   ng-controller="myController"  >
<div gridster="gridsterOpts">
<ul>
<li gridster-item="item" ng-repeat="item in Items">
   <div my-widget  data="item.obj" ng-class="item.classes"><!--ng-style="item.object" -->  
   </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and my script goes here

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',['gridster'])
app.controller('myController',function($scope){

    $scope.Items = [
{ sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj: {data:3222,message:"TotalCost",classes:["six design","fa-motorcycle"]}}]


});

 app.directive('myWidget',function(){

        return{

            restrict:"EA",
            scope:{ 
            data:'=',
            title:'=',
            label:'=',
            details:'=',
            message:'=',
            },
            templateUrl:'spare.html',
            }

    });
```

and my css:

```
six design{


text align:right;
float:left;
}
```

and spare html goes here

```
< span ng-controller="myController" >
    <h5>{{data.message}}<h5>
        <h3>{{data.details}}</h3>
                <h3>{{data.label}}</h3>
                    <h2>${{data.data}}</h2>

                    <h4>{{data.title}}</h4>


    </span>
```

and now i just need to include ng-class  array  i.e ="classes" in obj only and then how to bind that in html and i should get all the css which i had applied to them  and i also  i should render all my font icons

```
like `obj:{ data:3222,message:"TotalCost" ,classes:"fa fa-level-up"}`

and how to bind it in hmtl
```

Comment: anyone please help me out

Comment: for which div you want to add the class

Comment: <div my-widget  data="item.obj" ng-class="item.classes">

Comment: @pradeep that doesn't make sense, you are adding an icon on top of your directive. Don't you want your icon be **next** to it instead? e.g. `<span ng-class="data.classes"></span>` (inside your template) with `"fas fa-motorcycle"` icon

Comment: aleksey solovey i. Want two send fa icons into obj lo i want that to bind in html .please let me know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add even an array to `ng-class`,

You have classess in `item.obj` so change **`ng-class="item.classes"`** to **`ng-class="item.obj.classes"`**

```
<div style="background: yellow;width: 50px;" ng-repeat="item in Items">

    <span style="margin-left: 10px" ng-repeat="class in item.obj.classes" ng-class="class" class="fa"></span>
    <div my-widget  data="item.obj"></div>
</div>
```

Also never use classnames with spaces so change ,`six design` to `six-design`

so css will be,

```
.six-design{
  text align:right;
  float:left;
}
```

and the object changes to,

`classes:["six-design","fa-motorcycle"]`

The object is,

```
$scope.Items = [
  { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj:{data:8988643347,right:'',title:'Income',classes:["style1","fa fa-apple","fa fa-youtube-square","fa-motorcycle"]}},
 { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj: {data:65476756,right:'',title:"Population",classes:["fa fa-map-marker","style2"] }},
{ sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj: {data:54564545,right:'',title:"Users",classes:["fa fa-youtube-square","style3"]}},
{ sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj: {data:123.33,label:"Money",classes:["design1","design2"]}},
{ sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj: {data:3222,details:"Amount",classes:["design3","fa fa-shopping-cart","fa fa-motorcycle"]}},
{ sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0,  obj: {data:3222,message:"TotalCost",classes:["sixdesign","fa-motorcycle"]}}]
```

[**Here is a working plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/rSML5ICydmrFsRxuDbVP?p=preview)

Comment: I had tried it if i need to include one more font icon in it  the first icon is disappearing so thats why i want to include that in obj so that  i can i add  multiple icons can  i do that please help me out

Comment: means didnt get you, at a time you want to add 2 font icons??

Comment: thanks sravan you had understand what i need please help me out from it

Comment: if i need to add one more font icon the first icon disappearing and the css which is for 1st one is reflected same to the second one

Comment: but for a single element how can you show two icons? you want side by side?

Comment: suppose  i need to place one icon on top right and another one bottom right how can i do that and  i will apply different styles to that icon  if u provide me any source i will share my code

Comment: Any answers please

Comment: @pradeep, you want to apply two font icons to one element right?

Comment: Yea please  help me

Comment: exactly whats your requirement, and what are those two fonts you are going to apply?

Comment: in div i should place one icon  on the top right corner and and other on bottom right corner with  where width and height of div is dynamic and  there is no specific font icons  it can be any font icon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168521/discussion-between-pradeep-and-sravan).